# How to mutate columns in R based on ordering of subset of these columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

To begin with, let's suppose we have a dataset like this:

```r
data <- data.frame(
  id = 1:5,
  time = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2),
  obj_a_size = c(1, 3, 8, 4, 2),
  obj_a_cuteness = c(3, 6, 4, 1, 2),
  obj_b_size = c(5, 4, 4, 2, 5),
  obj_b_cuteness = c(6, 2, 10, 9, 6),
  obj_c_size = c(3, 6, 7, 1, 6),
  obj_c_cuteness = c(10, 1, 6, 8, 8)
)
```

It has columns concerning whole experiment (like `time`) and object-specific columns (like `X_size` and `X_cuteness`). These objects are ordered randomly, though, so I'd like to mutate these column to order the objects by size for each experiment separately. The result I expect to be like that:

```r
data <- data.frame(
  id = 1:5,
  time = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2),
  obj_max_size = c(5, 6, 8, 4, 6),
  obj_max_cuteness = c(6, 1, 4, 1, 8),
  obj_2nd_size = c(3, 4, 7, 2, 5),
  obj_2nd_cuteness = c(10, 2, 6, 9, 6),
  obj_min_size = c(1, 3, 3, 1, 2),
  obj_min_cuteness = c(3, 6, 10, 8, 2)
)
```

Notice that cuteness isn't ordered descending or ascending, but I want cuteness to be considered part of an object and set `obj_max_cuteness = obj_2_cuteness` wherever `obj_max_size = obj_2_size`, and so on.

Number of objects is known in advance (there are four of them), columns are known as well, and there are four columns describing each object. There is no missing data. I'm willing to use any package, if necessary. Also, original dataset is about 500k by 30, so bonus points for quick or memory-friendly code.

EDIT: Some noticed that the description is not very clear. What I'm after is a bit object-oriented thing: in the case above each object within experiment could be described as such (`X` in `obj_X_` means that it belongs to experiment no. `X`):

```
obj_1_a = {"size": 1, "cuteness": 3}
obj_1_b = {"size": 5, "cuteness": 6}
obj_1_c = {"size": 3, "cuteness": 10}
obj_2_a = {"size": 3, "cuteness": 6}
...
```

I want to reorder them by size so that (in the resulting data frame):

```
obj_1_max = {"size": 5, "cuteness": 6}
obj_1_2nd = {"size": 3, "cuteness": 10}
obj_1_min = {"size": 1, "cuteness": 3}
obj_2_max = {"size": 6, "cuteness": 1}
...
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  Is the expected output. correct

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?
The min and max value calculations are straightforward. To find the 2nd max you need to do a bit more work. My interpretation of the 2nd values is that it is the 2nd value of the sorted and unique values. My output differs from yours but that may be due to a different interpretation of what you mean by the 2nd value. My reading: you are looking for the first value down from the max value; from the groups of 3 columns (size, cuteness).

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(
      id = 1:5,
      time = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2),
      obj_a_size = c(1, 3, 8, 4, 2),
      obj_a_cuteness = c(3, 6, 4, 1, 2),
      obj_b_size = c(5, 4, 4, 2, 5),
      obj_b_cuteness = c(6, 2, 10, 9, 6),
      obj_c_size = c(3, 6, 7, 1, 6),
      obj_c_cuteness = c(10, 1, 6, 8, 8)
    )

obj_max_size <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contains('size')) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(obj_max_size = max(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(obj_max_size)

obj_min_size <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contains('size')) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(obj_min_size = min(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(obj_min_size)

obj_2nd_size <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contains('size')) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  distinct(value) %>%
  arrange(desc(value)) %>%
  slice(2) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(obj_2nd_size = value)

obj_max_cuteness <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contains('cuteness')) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(obj_max_cuteness = max(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(obj_max_cuteness)

obj_min_cuteness <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contains('cuteness')) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(obj_min_cuteness = min(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(obj_min_cuteness)

obj_2nd_cuteness <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contains('cuteness')) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  distinct(value) %>%
  arrange(desc(value)) %>%
  slice(2) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(obj_2nd_cuteness = value)


output <- bind_cols(id = data$id, obj_max_size, obj_min_size, obj_2nd_size, obj_max_cuteness, obj_min_cuteness, obj_2nd_cuteness)
```

With `output` looking like this:

```
> output
# A tibble: 5 x 7
     id obj_max_size obj_min_size obj_2nd_size obj_max_cuteness obj_min_cuteness obj_2nd_cuteness
  <int>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
1     1            5            1            3               10                3                6
2     2            6            3            4                6                1                2
3     3            8            4            7               10                4                6
4     4            4            1            2                9                1                8
5     5            6            2            5                8                2                6
```

Comment: Well, not really, I updated the question to provide more details. I don't want to order `size` and `cuteness` **separately**, but order them as if they belonged to one object and by `size` only.